# TypeError when modifying tf.keras.Optimizer parameter

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tf.keras, tensorflow1.15

I have been trying to implement a (heavily-inspired) Gradient-Accumulation wrapper for my Adam optimizer, as shown below:

```
class AccumOptimizer(tf.keras.optimizers.Optimizer):

    def __init__(self, optimizer, steps_per_update=1, **kwargs):

        super(AccumOptimizer, self).__init__(name="AccumOptimizer", **kwargs)
        self.optimizer = optimizer
        self.steps_per_update = steps_per_update
        self.iterations = tf.Variable(0, dtype='int64', name='iterations')
        self.cond = tf.equal(self.iterations % self.steps_per_update, 0)
        self.lr = self.optimizer.learning_rate
        self.optimizer.learning_rate = tf.cond(self.cond,
                                               lambda: self.optimizer.learning_rate,
                                               lambda: tf.constant(0, tf.float32))
        ...
```

But seem to butt into the following TypeError when I try to train:

```
TypeError: __array__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

which points to the part where `self.optimizer.learning_rate` is updated based on `self.cond`, although I'm sure that `tf.cond`should return a single value if the true/false function returns a singleton list.

I'm using Tensorflow 1.15.x (and constrained to this version, sadly).

Any ideas how this could be circumvented?

Comment: On which line you are getting the error, kindly mention the line number too...

Comment: Hi, I tried to figure out how to reference line numbers here, but no luck.
The error occurs at the line where:
```self.optimizer.learning_rate = tf.cond( ... ) ```